# IE8 seems to execute js before css is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8

I've got a weird problem. I'm using Bootstrap for a website that has to be optimized for IE8. When i test the html prototype in a real IE8 (no IE emulation) the javascript seems to be executed before the website is rendered.

To prevent this I placed the javascript at the bottom of the body and the script is surrounded by a window load function.

Do i miss something? I don't want to use a SetTimeout.

A short js code example.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // for example a function that resets the sliders offset
    function reset_slider() {
        $('.slider-main').css({'margin-top': '0px'});
    }
    reset_slider();
}
```

All Browsers beside IE8 execute this script after the site is rendered.

Thanks in advance
Marcus

Comment: have you try $(window).load()?

Comment: yes, as i wrote the script is surrounded by a window load function

Comment: you could post some minimal code to reproduce this, we are not telepaths here

Comment: i added some minimal code

Answer (score 1):

Set your js function to load after the page has.

```
window.onload = yourfunction
```

or you could use:

```
<body onload="yourfunction();">
```

Comment: nope, the result is the same. The Javascript is executed before the css is rendered properly